# loop in python to create folders: "The system cannot find the path specified"

Tags: python, loops, directory, mkdir, shutil

I am using os.path.join and os.mkdir to create folders on a loop.I would like to create a folder with the city name/inputs/b-d.

However, returns error. Similar behavior to this:

```
import shutil, os
PATH_TEST=r'C:\Users\Ricardo\Dropbox\test'

d = {'Municipalities': ['NY', 'Boston']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
for index in range(len(df)):
    aaa = os.path.join(PATH_TEST,df['Municipalities'][index],'inputs',"b-d")
    if not os.path.exists(aaa):
        os.mkdir(aaa)
```

Error:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_23524\2121887104.py in <cell line: 6>()
      7     aaa = os.path.join(PATH_TEST,df['Municipalities'][index],'inputs',"b-d")
      8     if not os.path.exists(aaa):
----> 9         os.mkdir(aaa)

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Users\\Ricardo\\Dropbox\\test\\NY\\inputs\\b-d'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would need to see your file system to answer fully but it seems likely that you're trying to create multiple folders e.g. NY, inputs and b-d which os.mkdir will not handle.

Instead I recommend swapping out os.mkdir with [os.makedirs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs).

Answer (score 1):

Most probable issue here is you are trying to create folder inside a folder that does not exist.

What do I mean? Your desired folder structure is like this `city_name/inputs/b-d`. When you check if it exists, it checks if `b-d` folder exists. If it doesn't it tries to create it.

Problem is that you are trying to create it inside folder `inputs` that also doesn't exist and that is why you get an error. NOTE: this would also happen if a parent folder `city_name` doesn't exist.

***To fix*** this you have to approach this iteratively according to the folder structure. First create `city_name` then `inputs` and then `b-d`.